# Why is this image not appearing where it should in this code?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, article, debugging, atom

I was trying to write an article in laTex and I attempted to incorporate the following image:

[image: Image I needed]

I wrote the following code - you can ignore the substance of the text in the code, that is out of context, but it shows where I intend for the image to appear. In this case, between "diagram below" and "For example"

```
To illustrate this, let us consider the diagram representation of the 4 x 4 determinant tic tac toe matrix. 

Using this diagram below, we can see how Player 0 should mirror it - should player 1 play in a spot player 0 should then play in the grid square with the corresponding letter, as per the diagram below.
\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80mm,scale=0.9]{/Users/redacted/Downloads/######2.png}
  \caption{The progression of the round where Player 1 starts.}

\end{figure}

For example, should Player 1 go first and play, without loss of generality, in $a_{2, 2}$, then Player 0 should play in $a_{2, 1}$, and if Player 0 is to go first, then they can play in any square, then follow this strategy.
\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space



The reason that this yields a winning strategy is that one of the properties of the determinant of a matrix is:
```

Unfortunately, when I ran this code (I am using the Atom LaTex compiler on Mac), the image appeared after the last sentence in the code (properties of the determinant of a matrix is:) - in fact, on the next page! (illustrated on the images).

[image: Spot where the image should appear]

[image: Image appeared on the next page]

Does anybody know why this has happened, and if so, how I can fix it?

Edit: My preamble on the article is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhfoffset{0.2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Redacted}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.2in}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{\sc{Theorem}}
\newtheorem*{definition}{\sc{Definition}}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{\sc{Proposition}}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{\sc{Corollary}}
\newtheorem*{claim}{\sc{Claim}}
\newtheorem*{properties}{\sc{Properties}}
\newtheorem*{remark}{\sc{Remark}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\begin{document}
```

Here is the error log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \includegraphics 
                                 
l.82   \includegraphics
                       [width=\linewidth]{####.png}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                                         {####.png}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                                         {####.png}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#
                                           ###.png}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{##
                                            ##.png}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{###
                                             #.png}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.82   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{####
                                              .png}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 81 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.92 \end{document}
                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

(./Latex - Template.aux)
! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ... \endgroup \deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.92 \end{document}
                   
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.


! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 81 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.92 \end{document}
                   
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.92 \end{document}
                   
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

)
! Emergency stop.
<*> "Latex - Template.tex"
                          
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Comment: The sole purpose of a figure environment is to move the picture around where it fits.

Comment: Are there any error or warning messages in the log file? Incidentally, is the name of the graphics file really `######2.png`? The `#` ("hashtag") symbol has special meaning to TeX and LaTeX. What happens if you rename it to, say, `myfile.png`?

Comment: It is really ######2.png. I'll try renaming the file.

Comment: Yes it could. Incidentally, it shouldn't be necessary to specify the `.png` extension.

Comment: I changed it to "test.png" and it still hasn't worked. I'll post what is currently in the log (being new to LaTex, there are quite a few errors I am not used to interpreting).

Comment: And, for crying out loud, do get rid of the `\vspace{5mm}` spacers. And, change `\begin{figure}` to `\begin{figure}[h!]` if you don't want the `figure` environment to "float".

Comment: What do you mean by float? And as for the \vspace{5mm}, I can't seem to find a way to get spaces otherwise?

Comment: As I thought, the error log is extensive. I'll post the relevant parts.

Comment: Ok @Mico, I've posted the log. It is quite long - perhaps you could start with the error(s) that will immediately solve the problem, if you don't have time for them all.

Comment: If you really, really think that the running text needs to be separated by more whitespace from the floats, issue the instruction `\addtolength\intextsep{5mm}` in the preamble; do *not* engage in the typographically poor habit of visual formatting.

Comment: @Mico, so you are saying that if I simply add the above one line to the preamble, then if I hit return (once? twice?) space will be added?

Comment: @Gill - I don't understand the "if I hit return" part in your question? Do you mean, if I recompile the document"?

Comment: @Mico That is, if I hit return to start on a new line. For example starting a new line doesn't seem to add a space.

Comment: @Mico, if I hit the enter button, say, on a word document, it goes to a new line. On LaTex, it seems to simply continue, or sometimes the new paragraph has no spacing in between like a paragraph on word would (it looks like the same paragraph, just starting on the same line). I usually use the vspace on text (not on figures) as it seems to put that space you usually see in between paragraphs on word, but I agree it is messy. So, will your way automatically add a paragraph space when I press enter like I would on word?

Comment: @Gill - LaTeX is most definitely **not** like MS Word ... in this regard, and in many many other regards. For sure, you didn't see me advocating to "hit return", did you? LaTeX is a typesetting system, not a word processor. Hint: a single blank line introduces a paragraph break; leaving more than one blank line does absolutely nothing -- and that's by design.

Comment: A single blank line introduces a paragraph break with no larger spacing between the lines of a paragraph and the line between paragraphs. vspace 5mm adds a larger space between paragraphs. What is the purpose of your preamble line? The MS Word was just to clarify what hit return meant.

Comment: You must distinguish between typography decisions and the text of document itself. The first one uses many rules, one of then is rule of the same repeating elements. There are two people: typographer, who does typographic decision and is able to program TeX to realize such decision and author who only writes paragraph after paragraph separarted by blank line in the TeX input. The space between paragraphs (repeated - they must be the same) is typographic decision. Typographers program macros where decision about paragraph shape is implemented. Inserting \vskip inside the text is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for posting a clipping from the log file. Something appears to have gone badly wrong -- according to the first error message, the instruction `\includegraphics` wasn't recognized; this will happen if the `graphicx` package wasn't loaded for some reason.

The demo code shown below -- in particular, the `[h!]` placement specifier -- will *generally* place the `figure` environment right where you want it to be. I use the qualifier "generally" deliberately: If there isn't enough space left on the current page to place the `figure` (a "float" in LaTeX jargon) *on that page*, LaTeX will place it at the top of the next page -- and fill up the remaining space on the current page with the next block of text, whatever that may be. According to your code, the graph is set to be 8cm wide -- and presumably, *at least* that tall. Try shrinking the width to 5 or 6 cm?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\begin{document}
Using this diagram below, we can see how Player 0 should mirror it - should player 1 play in a spot player 0 should then play in the grid square with the corresponding letter, as per the diagram below.

\begin{figure}[h!] 
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=80mm,scale=0.9]{/Users/redacted/Downloads/somefilename} % no need to specify ".png"
  \caption{The progression of the round where Player 1 starts.}
\end{figure}

For example, should Player 1 go first and play, without loss of generality, in $a_{2, 2}$, then Player 0 should play in $a_{2, 1}$, and if Player 0 is to go first, then they can play in any square, then follow this strategy.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, @Mico, adding the [h!] did not seem to make a difference. Did you do anything else?

Comment: I'll try renaming the image

Comment: That didn't change anything either...

Comment: @Gill - Where on the page does LaTeX place the `figure` right now? And where on the page does the call-out to the figure occur? If it happens close to the bottom of the page, there simply may not be enough space available on that page to place the figure -- LaTeX will *not* create an overfull page...

Comment: That is a possibility. I will shrink the image and try.

Comment: that appears to be the solution! Thanks - perhaps you should add that to your answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Gill - I did write, "If there isn't enough space left on the current page to place the figure (a "float" in LaTeX jargon) on that page, LaTeX will place it at the top of the next page". Is that too subtle? Maybe I should italicize "on that page".

Comment: Ah, I missed that focusing on the code in your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico The TeX special character `#` cannot be a reason of the error here. Try to name your file `####2.png` an use `\icludegraphics{####2}`. No error is here. The filenames can have such characters `#$&` etc. and TeX is able to not interpret them in special way if they are in the context of file name. For example `\input ab#$cd.tex`

Comment: @wipet - I was merely commenting on the error message -- "A number should have been here; I inserted `0`'." -- reported by the OP himself. `####1.png` is definitely ok as a filename; however, `####.png` apparently is not.

Comment: @wipet - I've rephrased the first paragraph of my answer to focus more strongly on the fact that `####.png` generates an error (or warning?) message.

Comment: @Mico you are not right. `####.png` works. But the snippet of log with many error messages first say `\includegraphics` is udefined control sequence, i.e. is ignored. Then [width= is printed. The `\linewidth` is a counter not followed by a dimen, so a number must be here and a dimen unit after such number (next two errors). The OP totally does not undertsand how TeX works and the log presented here is from his another experiment where `\includegraphics` was not defined at all.

Comment: Isn't \includegraphics defined with the graphicx package?

Comment: @wipet -- Thanks. It looks like I misunderstood what was actually happening in the OP's example code.