# How to centre a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, matrices, article, atom

I have inserted a matrix into my LaTex article using the following code:

```
For a $3 * 3$ grid, given as

\begin{bmatrix}

  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
\end {bmatrix}\\

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
The determinant is: $ a (ei-hf) - b (di -gf) + c (dh - ge)$
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

I was wondering if there was possibly a way to centre this matrix? What code would I need to add? I am using Atom for Mac.

Edit: Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhfoffset{0.2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{redacted}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.2in}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{\sc{Theorem}}
\newtheorem*{definition}{\sc{Definition}}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{\sc{Proposition}}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{\sc{Corollary}}
\newtheorem*{claim}{\sc{Claim}}
\newtheorem*{properties}{\sc{Properties}}
\newtheorem*{remark}{\sc{Remark}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, whether the `amsmath` package is loaded (and, if so, if it's loaded with the option `fleqn`), and how or where the `definition` environment is defined. Incidentally, your current code *must* be generating a slew of warning and/or error messages; what do they say?

Comment: @Mico, my code seems to be running fine otherwise - though if there are errors you find I would appreciate pointing them out. I think atom is using an auto debugger. I will post my preamble into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make your code snippets compilable and in an attempt to focus on what's relevant for the issue at hand, I've come up with the following minimum working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem*{definition}{\sc{Definition}}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Determinant of a $3 * 3$ grid. For a $3 * 3$ grid, given as

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space

\begin{bmatrix}

  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
\end {bmatrix}\\

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
The determinant is: $ a (ei-hf) - b (di -gf) + c (dh - ge)$
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

This MWE generates the following trail of messages in the log file:

```
 ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 \begin{bmatrix}
                    
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.15 \end {bmatrix}
                   \\
? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--16
```

Some comments and observations:

- The `! Missing $ inserted.` messages are generated because `bmatrix` *must* occur in math mode.
- There should be no blank lines in math mode.
- To center-set an equation (or matrix) without generating an equation number, use `\[` and `\]` directives. They initiate and terminate display-math mode, which centers its contents horizontally.
- The `\sc` command does not take an argument. Moreover, it's deprecated under LaTeX2e. Do please replace `\newtheorem*{definition}{\sc{Definition}}` with `\newtheorem*{definition}{\scshape Definition}`.
- The `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` message is generated because of the unnecessary `\\` directive at the end of the `\end {bmatrix}\\` line.

With the suggested modifications in place, the code no longer issues error and warning messages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\newtheorem*{definition}{\scshape Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Determinant of a $3 * 3$ grid. For a $3 * 3$ grid, given as
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
The determinant is: $ a (ei-hf) - b (di -gf) + c (dh - ge)$
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this. Seeing as you seem to have a keen eye for bugs in LaTex, could you please take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550226/why-is-this-image-not-appearing-where-it-should-in-this-code?noredirect=1#comment1389705_550226, one of my other questions? It seems to be something in your alley.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative can be to use the enviroment `center` to centre a matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhfoffset{0.2cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{redacted}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.2in}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{\sc{Theorem}}
\newtheorem*{definition}{\sc{Definition}}
\newtheorem*{proposition}{\sc{Proposition}}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{\sc{Corollary}}
\newtheorem*{claim}{\sc{Claim}}
\newtheorem*{properties}{\sc{Properties}}
\newtheorem*{remark}{\sc{Remark}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition} For a $3 * 3$ grid, given as

\begin{center}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% <- start enviroment center
    $\begin{bmatrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i 
    \end{bmatrix}$ 
\end{center}

\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
The determinant is: $ a (ei-hf) - b (di -gf) + c (dh - ge)$
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]